# Android ninepatch tool source code

Tags: android, nine-patch

where could I find the source code of the "ninepatch" tool present in the Android SDK?
I assume it is a java application.
I'd like to make it better for my own use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find the NinePatch tool within the AOSP source located in `development/apps/NinePatchLab`. Of course, if you do not have the AOSP source, do not fret, as it can be located on [github](https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/apps/NinePatchLab), a single source file.